# Coulrophobia: the fear of clowns

Tags: character-development, child-characters

Can a child who has been sexually harassed by clowns be said to have 'coulrophobia: the fear of clowns' because of the fear and trauma she is undergoing?

I mean to ask if the word 'coulrophobia' can be used when she's scared because of the fact that she was harassed.

I'm writing a story on this girl, who was raped but was diagnosed to be coulrophobiac by the doctor. He didn't know, neither did he check whether she was raped.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE tapi.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  I don't see what this question has to do with writing though, even if it's research you're doing to help you write a particular character.  We're about the writing process here, not the specifics of the research.  Please stick around though and feel free to answer questions and ask others about writing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a research question unrelated to writing itself.

Comment: I appreciate your edit to add that you're writing a story about this topic.  Unfortunately, the question is still very off topic, because it's part of your research, not part of your writing.  Also: the word you want up top isn't "harassed" but "molested" or "assaulted" (if you don't want to just say "raped").

Comment: @Cyn I wanted to ask about the usage of the word, basically wanted to know whether it's applicable here in this context or not. But nevermind, which SE would be apt for asking this?

Comment: One close vote suggested that the question should be migrated to English.SE.  I didn't choose that option because of the story description part.  But a question just about the usage of the word could go to English.  You might also try Psychology.  But to answer the question, yes, if you have a fear of clowns *for any reason* you can be diagnosed with fear of clowns.  Phobias are often diagnosed based on symptoms, not underlying reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I would say no. The phobias are more in the realm of **irrational** fears, not **rational** ones. So she might *develop* coulrophobia, but she doesn't have it just because she got raped by somebody dressed as a clown.

She is more likely to fear that specific clown makeup; not the whole category of clowns in general. I can't imagine a doctor incompetent enough to diagnose "coulrophobia" because of a single incident. That isn't even a medical doctor's call; it is a clinical psychologist's call, and they don't diagnose phobias lightly.